# Sales Promotions concept and design with cron jobs

Tags: design, development-process, cron

I'm currently building an app that includes sales promotions. There is an option in the promotion that allows the manager to have a start and end date. I do not want the manager to have to manually select the winner, but I want my software to read that the end date was reached and auto close the promotion.

This sounds like a job for `cron`.

These are my options:

1. At night, run a single script that pulls all promotions across my
   entire database and updates promotions that have completed.
2. At the creation of the promotion record, queue up a cron to run at
   the custom end date.
3. Force the user to manually update promotion.

Any advice or previous experience would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What criteria will you use to choose the best option?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/334673/20756

Comment: @RobertHarvey What do you mean?

Comment: How will you choose which option to use?  Some options will be better for you than others.  What does "better" mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you want to make sure your application fulfills the following key tests

- When you run it, it searches for everything that needs doing and does it.
- If you run two or more instances at the same time. nothing breaks and the work gets done as normal.
- If it crashes half way through, nothing bad happens and you can just run it again.
- You have some way of excluding things from its search. So you can tell it to ignore promotion X for example.
- You have a way to set a manual approval/publish step before the results are sent out to live customers. You can turn this off once you are sure of the process, but to begin with it is vital.